# Redirect user to specific language url based on OS language in Cordova webview app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, localization, inappbrowser

I have following code in my index.html in a Cordova project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>MyBilli</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            var url = 'http://sub.domain.com/app/nl/login/' // change to whatever you want
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');
        }, false)
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The list of current Cordova plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 3.0.1 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
```

Is it possible to redirect a user based on his OS language (only 3 languages allowed: **en**, **fr** or **nl**) to a different url: sub.domain.com/app/**[en|fr|nl]**/login/

If **en**, **fr** or **nl** is not user's OS language, default to **en**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can get the devices language with https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/

You'd then just have to replace the url parts for what is picked up

Comment: Could you explain where in my code I should use this? In index.html or somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: You would use it where you are defining your urls, you'd replace the /nl/ part of your url with the result from navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(successCallback, errorCallback); https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/#navigatorglobalizationgetpreferredlanguage